# Rosbridge doesnt work at SOME smartphones

Tags: rosbridge, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello wise people,

I have made WEB application using HTML, JavaScript and Rosbridge to control my robot. Application works perfecty when launched on PC (windows/linux), netbook, laptop, some tablets and some smartphones. I repeat: **IT WORKS PERFECTLY**. However at SOME smartphones (both Android and Windows 8) the application launch, I can see all the graphics, I can use sliders and see numbers changing (witch means that JavaScript works) but no data is send or recieved.
So i'm guessing ROS and Rosbridge are ok and the problem is with those phones.

My question is: Why my app doesn't work on SOME phones? Does it require a specific version of OS? Or maybe some special libraries?

I'm using ROS Indigo.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246936/rosbridge-doesnt-work-at-some-smartphones/) by [NastyKhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/28407/nastykhan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-11-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you might want to check if your smart phone supports websocket. rosbridge does not work without websocket.

---

Originally posted by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) with karma: 634 on 2016-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NastyKhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/28407/nastykhan/) on 2016-11-02**:
Well it seems you might be right, thank you. I've done some research however and it look like websocket support it's not a matter of phone itself but rather it's intertet browser. Just look at these tables:

http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets

**Comment by [NastyKhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/28407/nastykhan/) on 2016-11-06**:
I did some testing. Basically switching to another browser helps, which makes me happy enough. Pity, my old phone with Android 2.3.4 doesn't support any other/newer browser. (Dont worry, old pal, we will fight together once again. Another time.)